# How to get Current Date, Time, Year from NSDate?

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents

Here is the situation

I have a method as

```
+ (NSDateComponents *)getTodayComponents {
    NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:today];
}
```

through which I can get day, month, year, hour, minute, and so on for **today**

Now I need to change the day, month and year which is coming from another `NSDate`, so my code looks like

```
- (void)datePickerView:(RSDFDatePickerView *)view didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [Helper getTodayComponents];
    self.transactionDate = date;
    NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);
    self.inputDateField.text =  [[Helper getDateFormatterForClient] stringFromDate:self.transactionDate];
    [self.inputDateField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

**Question**

How can I get year, day and month from `today` so that I can set up in todayComponents?

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSDateComponents`. There are obvious properties for the various components.

Comment: Do you mean the date that was selected on the picker? - i.e. the parameter `date`?  Just pass it to your helper function and use it instead of the new date object.

Answer (score 2):

From what I am understanding with your query what you want to achieve is the components of some other date which you are getting through picker and later modify those components to show the date in a `UITextField`.

So add or modify the existing method

```
+ (NSDateComponents *)getTodayComponentsFromDate:(NSDate *)theDate {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:theDate];
}
```

Or if you want to just display the date picked from date picker in a specific format, so i would suggest you to use `NSDateFormatter` to do that.